# gdb print std::list with big data

Tags: gdb, stdlist

I'd like to print std::list with data more than 200,000.
To save into file is not efficient.
File is too big, so it's not easy to handle.

```
std::list<Type_t> list;
struct Type_t
{
    int a;
    char *b;
    ...
};
```

"p list" is available, but I want to partially print or save into smaller file.